# Multiple row form - how to update specific row when input field names are same in column

Tags: javascript, forms, input, row

I have a report that, when it goes into input mode, creates a form where you have multiple rows of data, and on each row, there is a button and an input field.  The input field name is the same for each row (it's easier for the CGI program to process the input that way).  What I would also like, but having trouble doing, is if the user clicks on the button of that row, it should automatically update the input field in that same row.  How can javascript find the input field for the same row where the button is?

I was stuck coming out of the gates, so don't even know where to start.

Here's a simplified version of the HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Frank</td>
<td>Burns</td>
<td><input type="text" name="overtime" value="1000"></td>
<td><input type="button" name="averageIN" value="Average In" onclick="return avgIN('1000,'2000');">
</tr><tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
<td><input type="text" name="overtime" value="500"></td>
<td><input type="button" name="averageIN" value="Average In" onclick="return avgIN('500,'2000');">
</tr>
</table>
```

Here's the incomplete javascript:

```
function avgIN(orig, avg) {

    let text = "Request to Average In Overtime:\n\n"+
       "Current OT Total: "+orig+"\n"+
       "Averaged In Total: "+avg+"\n\n"+
       "Click OK to accept";
    if (confirm(text) == true) {
        // do something here to set the overtime input field on the same row to the value of "avg"
        }
    else {
        alert("Average In function canceled");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use event delegation...

and do something like that:

```js
const myTable = document.querySelector('#my-table')

myTable.onclick = e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('button[data-avg-in]')) return // exit
  
  let 
    [orig, avg] = e.target.dataset.avgIn.split(',').map(Number)
  , txt =
`Request to Average In Overtime:

Current OT Total: ${orig} 
Averaged In Total: ${avg}

Click OK to accept`
       ;
  if (confirm(txt)) 
    {
    e.target.closest('tr').querySelector('input[name="overtime[]"]').value = 'avg'
    } 
  else 
    {
    alert('Average In function canceled');
    }
  }
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <tr>
    <td>Frank</td>
    <td>Burns</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="overtime[]" value="1000"></td>
    <td><button data-avg-in="1000,2000" >Average In</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="overtime[]" value="500"></td>
    <td><button data-avg-in="500,2000" >Average In</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I think we need to remove the quotes around 'avg' (it's inserting the text "avg" instead of the actual number), but this seems like a viable solution. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I tried this and I'm having a big problem.  The HTML is all contained within a form, and after the user presses OK on the confirm() call, it submits the form (which I do not want).  It should just put data into the input field, but not submit the form.  Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: Another question: In this statement, "[orig, avg] = e.target.dataset.avgIn.split(',').map(Number", where is the "avgIn" defined?

Comment: I noticed that you changed "overtime" to "overtime[]".  This broke my code, so I changed it back to "overtime" (this way the post sends all the values separated by "~" and I can easily parse).  Is having it as overtime[] necessary to make this work?

Comment: @DonMerlin `let [orig, avg] =  <<<Array>>>`  is [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: @DonMerlin `e.target.dataset.avgIn.split(',').map(Number)` is : 1)`e.target` => event target == clicked element inside `#my-table`.
2)`e.target.dataset.avgIn` get the text inside `data-avg-in="xxx,yyy"` 3)`.split(',').map(Number)` separte `xxx`and`yyy` into an Array and change the string value into a Number value.

Comment: @DonMerlin = `you changed name="overtime" to "overtime[]"`  it is by convention, if you use the same name value several times, then this implies that you constitute an array, hence the addition of the `[]` for the readability of the code.after a few years of writing code, you will see for yourself that after a few years of coding, using writing conventions is essential to maintaining good mental health. This convention allows PHP to constitute an array during the submit of your form.

Comment: @DonMerlin this is the principle of HTML forms = sending data to a server. If this server does not exist the data is sent in a vacuum and the HTML page is reloaded. If you don't want this, you have to disable this mechanism, personally I use an `event.preventDefault()` on the `event==submit`. This question here is off the original topic, and you don't show any form in your topic. A simple search here should show you different possibilities for this problem.

Comment: I figured out the issue with the form submission.  I simply added type="button" to the <button> tag.  In my attempt to simply the example, I did remove the form as well as the extra rows (i.e., in my in-house HTML, the button and the input field are on different rows, but in the same column, so the "tr" nearby search failed.  I had to put them both in the same <td> and then used "td" instead of "tr".

Comment: The question I still have is regarding the e.target statement.  After ".dataset" there is ".avgIn".  This just happens to be my original function name, but this code replaces that function, so I'm confused as to why this doesn't throw an error.  Does this statement create the avgIn dataset?

Comment: @DonMerlin I thought you would have had the reflex to look at the MDN docs...https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: @DonMerlin for semantic reasons, the use of a table in a form is disapproved; and there are enough resources in HTML CSS to get impeccable forms... But since you don't indicate anything if your data is supposed to be sent back to a server or not, I don't know if you need a form or not , but in any case do not mix forms and tables on the same informal group...

Comment: My reflex is to use Google, I'm not as well-versed in the available resources as others, but thank you for that link, that was very helpful!  Regarding tables in forms, yes, I agree, but I'm trying to implement a change on an old program, and don't have the time/budget to redo the reporting aspect.  I'm just being tasked to add this javascript button.  Hope to re-do the whole thing down the road, but right now, just trying to get the button to work properly.